# ng serve doesn't generate dist folder anymore with new angular-cli webpack beta

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I initially started a project with beta 10 of the `angular-cli`, when I run `ng serve` at that point of time the dist folder would contain the compiled files that were generated by `ng serve`.

Now I upgraded my app to RC5 and `beta 11.webpack` of the `angular-cli` and `ng serve` doesn't generate the dist folder anymore.
This is problematic because I have a Spring Boot backend which is configured to map the dist folder as it's static folder.

Is there a way to get this behaviour with the webpack angular-cli as well?

Exact version of angular-cli is: `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2`

Edit: the point is that I need the auto compile from ng serve, I don't want to run ng build every time I make a change in the source files.

Comment: Try: `$ rm -rf dist tmp node_modules && npm install && ng build`

Comment: I edited the question, ng build generates a dist folder just fine, that is not the problem. Earlier ng serve also generated the dist folder. This is not the case anymore. I want that behaviour back.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use `ng build --watch`. It will be rebuilding the project on changes.

Explanation:

By running `ng build --help`, we can see what the --watch flag does:

> --watch                           Run build when files change.

Comment: I know this question is a bit dated but this solution only seemed to have worked partially for me. For instance in the very basic scenario where my app.component.ts has a variable called title and I display it using {{}} in app.component.html, changing it will rebuild the package but the variable won't be updated (similarly if I add a class variable and try to display it) the only thing that worked was adding html content in the view. I refreshed and reloaded and that didn't do anything

Answer (score 27):

The new angular-cli version with webpack will generate `dist` folder only after `ng build`.

`ng serve` works only in-memory now.

Comment: I know, that's why i asked the question in the first place :) The proxy functionality makes this obsolete though. I just proxy the api instead of serving the dist folder with spring boot.

Comment: I use the proxy and now with the latest cli it doesn't find my css etc.  like it did before.  Is there a way to proxy just the api calls and not anything else?

Comment: How can i trace my compile-time errors then? I use aot and I get some errors with line numbers but I cannot see the file.

Answer (score 7):

In the root folder of your angular2 project, run:

```
ng build
```

Or for production:

```
ng build --prod
```

This command will generate the dist folder.

Comment: Thanks, i know that, this is not the point: ng build does not compile on change like ng serve does.

Comment: it doesn't for angular cli 7

Answer (score 0):

In the root folder of your project run

```
ng serve --delete-output-path=false
```

or

```
ng serve --no-delete-output-path
```

This worked for me.

Comment: The above option wont work if you are using angular 6 or above, it was removed