# Angular-cli not generating dist directory with ng build

Tags: angular-cli

Here is what I have installed:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
node: 7.4.0
os: linux x64
@angular/common: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler: 2.4.9
@angular/core: 2.4.9
@angular/forms: 2.4.9
@angular/http: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
@angular/router: 3.4.9
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
```

I have looked at this post [Not generating dist folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034643/ng-serve-doesnt-generate-dist-folder-anymore-with-new-angular-cli-webpack-beta) , but I just want a dist directory generated so that I can link it with Express.  The command I am using is

```
ng build --base-href /apply/
```

I understand with ng serve the files are created in memory.  However I am not using ng serve.  I have a Express static path

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve('../../dist')));
```

Since the build command does not create the dist directory I cannot serve the angular application. The answer in the link (above) says to use the --watch argument.  Why do I have to do that? Shouldn't ng build create the dist directory?

Am I missing something obvious.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Secondary comment. If there is an error for example "ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically" does the build process abort ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I have learned. The reason there was no dist directory being created was due to the fact that there was a compiling error (in older cli version this was not the case).  The error was

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the value of this variable is needed by the template compiler (position 79:22 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AUTH_PROVIDERS in ...
```

I removed the dependency of AUTH_PROVIDERS from app_module.ts. Once this was done the project compiled ok.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem. The solution for me was to look in the `tsconfig.json` file and remove `dist` from the `excludes` section. Then I ran `ng build` and the `dist` folder was generated and put into the project root directory.

Also look at your `angular-cli.json` file to see if the `outdir` field is writing to `dist`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, perhaps the dist folder has actually been created (check in your Finder) but doesn't show in your text editor because, by default, your `.gitignore` file has /dist.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding a folder /dist manually, and run "ng build". So that I can see what is in there and copy things to upload to AWS S3.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 :- Go to angular.json and check for below line
**"outputPath": "../webapp",**

Step 2 :- Redirect to the path which is mentioned inside the **outputPath** you will get the dist file.

Answer (score 1):

The build folder will be listed in the **`angular.json`** file with parameter named **`outputPath`**. Just check the respective folder to get the production code.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "BuddyTranslator": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "./dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            ...
```

Here the directory name is dist. So, that the build files will be listed under dist folder in the source directory,

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was funny. I had opened a terminal(cmd) and distination was dist folder. So, the dist folder was locked. I closed the terminal and everything went OK.

Answer (score 0):

Find and add this in `angular.json` file, worked for me, finally got my dist with data.

```json
"build": {
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist"
  }
  ...
}
```