# Angular Image Path

Tags: angular, path, assets

This question is from the open source project.

All images are stored in assets folder and the file is located in app/customer folder from where the code to load images is specified. The code is -

```
<img src="assets//images/{{customer.gender | lowercase}}.png" class="details-image" alt="">
```

The folder structure is -

```
-app
 -customer
  -fileLocation
-assets
 -images
  -image1.png
```

The images load properly. My question is - 'How the images are loading even the files are located at different levels? I cannot see the settings anywhere.

Comment: "*different levels*" meaning?

Comment: The image is called from file which is located in app/customer and the image is located in assets folder which is at same level as app folder. But nothing is specified like go one level up, then assets folder .....

Comment: @Aparna reason is simple Angular-cli knows about assets folder

Comment: Thanks Vikas. Angular knewed it, but I did not knew how the angular knew it?

Comment: @Aparna That's why we are using a framework to make our job easier if you use relative path and  When you move your component to another directory (which has a different depth) the path will be broken that's why the absolute path is a good practice and cli allow you to do it.:)

Comment: @Vikas True..  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using angular6  you are customize your assets in angular.json file for angular4/5 you can .angular-cli.json

[image]
In the screenshot you can see the path hierarchy for assets.

---

Also when you build your project `ng build`, then from the generated `dist` folder you can see the assets folder path relation to `index.html` file 
[image]

Comment: Yes, I can see this code specified in angular.json file. It means when I mention 'assets' the path will get mapped to 'src/assets'. Am I correct?

Comment: no, from the dist folder you can view this relative path

Comment: your app is just the `index.html` file since it a single-page-application. So `index.html`  and 'assets` folder are at the same level. so the  `root-path ie /` is folder containing `index.html` file. so anywhere in the application it should be either `"/assets/<path to resource>"` or ` "assets/<path to resource>"`

Comment: No, but dist folder is created after the build. I have not build the project.

Comment: when you do `ng-serve` then angular-cli creates something like `dist` in the memory not on disk for server the content fast for development purpose.

Since it is in in-memory we don't see that

Comment: can you look into your angular.json file for `"outputPath": "dist/reactive-form-demo",`

Comment: Okay. I understood now what you said is mentioned as one of the answer for this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034643/ng-serve-doesnt-generate-dist-folder-anymore-with-new-angular-cli-webpack-beta/39686160. Thanks a lot vivek :-). Accepting your answer.

Comment: glad that you understood the magic what angular-cli is doing for us to make the devlopment faster

Comment: I am really grateful to all of you. :-)